# Accessing parent properties and overridden methods in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have parent and child classes as follows:

```
abstract class ParentObj {
    private $data;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->data = array(1,2,3);
        var_dump($this->data);

        $this->method();
    }
    public function method(){
        echo "ParentObj::method()";
    }
}
class ChildObj extends ParentObj {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump($this->data);
    }
    public function method(){
        echo "ChildObj::method()";
    }
}
```

The expected output:

```
array(1,2,3)
ChildObj::method()
array(1,2,3)
```

The actual output:

```
array(1,2,3)
ParentObj::method()
NULL
```

The problem is, the child object cannot access the data property and the parent refuses to call the overridden method in the child.

Am I doing something wrong, or does anybody have any ideas?

**EDIT:** I should clarify that I am instantiating a ChildObj as `$child = new ChildObj()`

Comment: Okay, changing the private to protected fixes the property access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the methods were actually declared private, not public as in my post, thus suffering the same symptom as the $data property.

Answer (score 10):

You've declared `data` as private, so ChildObj won't be able to access it - you need to make it protected instead:

```
protected $data;
```

My PHP (5.2.8) prints `ChildObj::method()` - are you running an older version?